# текст накладывается сам на себя

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня при загрузке строк в тхт,они накладываются друг на друга,из за этого в тхт отображается только последний пароль
Вопрос, как можно сделать так что бы каждый вариант который генерируется программной был в отдельной строке
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

```
A = "0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890-=\.,/qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm,.;["
base = len(A)
n = 0
l = 0

while True:
  password = ""
  temp = n
  while len(password) < 1:
    rest = temp % 82
    temp =temp // 82
    password = A[rest] + password
  print(n, password)
  F = open("txt","w")
  for i in password:
    F.write(str(n)+ password + '\n')
    F.close
  
  
  if password == A[-1]*1:
    l += 1
    n = 0

  else:
    n += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

A = "0123456789QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890-=\.,/qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm,.;["
base = len(A)
n = 0
l = 0

while True:
  password = ""
  temp = n
  while len(password) < 1:
    rest = temp % 82
    temp =temp // 82
    password = A[rest] + password
  print(n, password)
  F = open("txt","a")
  for i in password:
    F.write(str(n)+ password + '\n')
    F.close
  
  if password == A[-1]*1:
    l += 1
    n = 0
  else:
    n += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Эту строку `F = open("txt","w")` изменить на `F = open("txt","a")`

Второй аргумент (`w` или `a`) определяет способ открытия файла.

w - только запись. Полностью очищает документ и записывает новые данные;

a - чтение и запись. Открывает документ, не очищая его. Новые данные добавляются после старых.

Answer (score 0):

```
  F = open("txt","w")
  for i in password:
    F.write(str(n)+ password + '\n')
    F.close
```

У вас сразу три ошибки в этом коротком коде:

- файл перезаписывается на каждой итерации цикла `while`, используйте режим добавления в файл `'a'` вместо простой записи `'w'`
- цикл по буквам `password` вам не нужен, вы же записываете `password` сразу целиком
- вы закрываете файл на каждой итерации цикла записи, это приведёт к ошибке "попытка записи в закрытый файл"

Таким образом, лучше использовать такой код и не закрывать файл вручную, за вас это сделает *менеджер контекста*:

```
  with open("txt","a") as f:
    f.write(str(n)+ password + '\n')
```